# VBA open multiple files, from different folders based on cell criteria in columns

Tags: excel, vba, file

I have the following code which I have been able to modify to open a batch of files that were saved down to a single folder, meaning the path was always static.

However, I now need to capture the data, that the macro extracts, from a number of sources, which I have reference to in the file that the macro is run from.

I need to alter what was my “FoldPath” string (change it all together) to base the string on the folder address in a specific column, which will change progressing down the column.

Ultimately I have the file path in a specific column and the folder name in the adjacent column and would like to extract the data for every file in the list.

Thanks for any help that can be offered

```
Sub FileUpdateInfo()


Dim FoldPath As String

FoldPath = ("C:\Users\xpa\Desktop\Projects\IPRs")


For Each d In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Files").Range("A2", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Files").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))


Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FoldPath & "\" & d.Value, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)


LastSaved = owb.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")

d.Offset(, 1).Value = LastSaved


LastAut = owb.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Author")

d.Offset(, 2).Value = LastAut


LastAut = owb.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Creation Date")

d.Offset(, 3).Value = LastAut



owb.Close SaveChanges = False


Next d


End Sub
```

Comment: What column are the folder paths in? I take it the correct folder path is in the same row as `d`. And why is your second `LastAut` not `CreationDate`?

Comment: Comment out `FoldPath = ("C:\Users\xpa\Desktop\Projects\IPRs")` and change `FolderPath` to something like `d.Offset(,column number).Text`

Comment: Thank you - after using the file path as a string I couldn't get my head around altering it but this did the trick. (and the LastAut was a typo when putting this online)